# Dependency issue installing libpq-dev on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, apt

I'm trying to install libpq-dev (PostgreSQL library) on Ubuntu 11.10. When I run apt-get I get the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
libpq-dev : Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And then when I go to install libkrb5-dev, I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 krb5-multidev : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libk5crypto3 (= 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

At which point I'm completely lost as it seems like I already have the required packages, but krb5-multidev wants older versions, is that right? How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed some packages from a newer version of Ubuntu, or from a third party PPA, which conflict with the Ubuntu version you originally installed.

To fix this problem:

1. Disable the PPA, if there is one.
2. Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and verify that the Ubuntu version being used is the one you want (e.g. `lucid`, `precise`, etc.).
3. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to resync all of your packages to the correct versions. This will both upgrade and downgrade as necessary to get your system back in sync.

Comment: I've never seen `apt-get dist-upgrade` downgrade packages in this kind of situation...

Comment: I checked to see if there were any PPAs installed and while there was one, it was disabled. I've  run update and dist-upgrade and the problem is still not fixed. Thanks for the attempt, but any other ideas?

Comment: It looks like the issue was actually due to some 3rd party software (Parallels) that screwed around with various packages. Thanks!